# Is ordinal analysis a non-recursive project?

Tags: logic, computability, ordinals, proof-theory, foundations

A recursive ordinal is an ordinal that is the order-type for some recursive relation (i.e. a recursive well-ordering).  We can represent recursive ordinals as natural numbers using Kleene's $O$, an ordinal notation system.  Unfortunately, the set of natural numbers which are in Kleene's $O$ is not recursive, or even recursively enumerable.  And it is not effectively decidable whether two numbers represent the same ordinal or not.

But suppose you had an oracle $M$ which could tell what precisely numbers are notations in Kleene's $O$, and whether two numbers represent the same ordinal.  Let $O'$ be the set of equivalence classes of elements of Kleene's $O$, under the equivalence relation of two numbers representing the same ordinal.  Let us enumerate (or code) all recursively axiomatized theories with natural numbers, so that $T_n$ represents the $n^{th}$ such theory.  Then let us define a function $f$ from the set of natural numbers to $O'$ as follows: $f(n)$ is the element of $O'$ corresponding to the proof-theoretic ordinal of the theory $T_n$.  (The proof-theoretic ordinal of a theory is the least ordinal that the theory cannot prove the well-foundedness of.)

My question is, does there exist a Turing machine which, given access to the oracle $M$, can compute the function $f$?  To put it another way, if a computer program knew exactly what recursive ordinals there were, could it find the proof-theoretical ordinal of all recursively axiomatizable theories?  If the answer is no, as I suspect it may be, what other oracle do you require to do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the answer you want is "yes, once you make it rigorous". For example, if we are talking about theories of second-order arithmetic then it is clear what "T proves that index $e$ computes a well ordering" will mean. For theories of first-order arithmetic, the definition is more subtle, but for example it might mean that $T$ proves a certain axiom scheme that represents transfinite induction up to $e$, or $T$ proves some other axiom scheme.

In any case, the following will apply as long as "T proves that index $e$ computes a well ordering" means that $T$ proves some (possibly infinite) set of sentences that is uniformly r.e. given the index $e$; we will call the set $S(e)$.

*There is another caveat that I am more nervous about.* You are talking about arbitrary indices for computable well orderings. Usually, when we do ordinal analysis, we look at particular "nice" indices, which compute the well order in a nice way. It is known that there are various tricks that one can do with indices to hide what they are doing. For example, there is an index $e$ that really computes an order of type $\omega$, but Peano Arithmetic does not prove that the order computed by $e$ has a least element. So does that mean, in your setup, that the least ordinal that PA cannot prove to be well founded is $\omega$?

So, really, statements that claim to identify the proof-theoretic ordinal have to be understood as informal interpretations of particular results, rather than being statements about a formal definition of "proof theoretic ordinal". See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52926/proof-theoretic-ordinal/52927#52927

I am going to ignore that temporarily, and give an answer in the spirit of the question, because it shows a key fact about $\mathcal{O}$. But I am not convinced that the thing that is being found is really "the proof theoretic ordinal of $T$".

Now I will proceed to the construction. Given an index $t$ for $T$, the statement "For every $i \in S(e)$, $T$ proves the sentence with Goedel number $i$" can be written as an arithmetical formula $\phi(t,e)$, where the same formula $\phi$ works for all $t$ and $e$. Basically, $\phi$ says: whenever $e$ enumerates a formula $i$, there is a formal proof of that formula from the set of axioms enumerated by $t$.

Thus there is also an arithmetical formula $\psi(t,e)$ which says that $e$ computes a linear order of $\omega$, and $\phi(t,e)$ does not hold but, for every $e' <_e e$, $\phi(t,e')$ does not hold. The last part quantifies over every proper initial segment of the ordering computed by $e$. Note that if $e$ actually computes a well ordering, then $\psi(t,e)$ holds if and only if the order type of $e$ is (in some imprecise sense, but I think the one you mean) the "proof theoretic ordinal of $T$."

The index $\mathcal{O}$ is very strong. In particular, given any arithmetical formula, we can use $\mathcal{O}$ to tell whether that formula is true or false.
Formally, this is the fact that $\emptyset^{(\omega)} <_T \text{HJ}(\emptyset) = \mathcal{O}$. Now, given $t$, we can do the following: enumerate all values of $e$. For each one, first ask whether $e \in \mathcal{O}$. If not, move on to the next value of $e$. If $e \in \mathcal{O}$, ask whether $\psi(e,t)$ holds. If so, we have found the ordinal for $t$. Otherwise, move on to the next value of $e$. This will find some sort of "proof theoretic ordinal" $e$, subject to my caveat above.

Comment: What if you defined the proof-theoretic ordinal as follows: the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that $PRA$ + quantifier-free transfinite induction up to $\alpha$ proves $Con(T)$?

Comment: That is still an arithmetical property of an index of $\alpha$, so the same method would apply, with the same caveat. The real situation with proof theoretical ordinals is that "you know it when you see it", but trying to make a very precise definition is difficult because of strange counterexamples. So it is still an informal notion.

Comment: Why would the same caveat apply?  For instance, is there a set of indices for the ordinals less than $\epsilon_0$ such that $PRA$ + quantifier-free transfinite induction using those indices does NOT prove $Con(PA)$?

Comment: You could make an index $e$ so that $|e|$ is really $\omega$, but the induction scheme for induction on $e$ implies Con(PA) over PRA. The issue is that the computation of the ordinal may ask, at each step, whether it has seen a counterexample to Con(PA), and can then do something different (like become non-well-founded)  if it sees one. If it becomes non-well-founded in a simple predictable way models where Con(PA) fails, then PRA should be able to disprove a specific instance of the induction scheme under the assumption that Con(PA) fails.

Comment: IN particular, the order I have in mind is $0 < 1 < 2 < \cdots < n < \cdots <   n+3 < n+2 < n+1$ if $n+1$ is the first number that is a counterexample to Con(PA). So under Con(PA) this order is just $\omega$ and when Con(PA) fails with minimal witness $n+1$ the order is $n + \omega^*$. So transfinite induction should not hold for this order unless Con(PA) holds; the instance that should fail is $\phi(m)$ that says "for all $n < m$, $n$ is not a counterexample to Con(PA)". It is the case for this order that $(\forall b)[(\forall a <_e b)[\phi(a)] \to \phi(b)]$.